# Deserialization xml into object C# (Cannot get xml loaded into the object)

Tags: c#, xml

**Below is my code for the object, I'm using an postasync call to get the data from a Web Api but stuck on this part**

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.constructivity.com/api/Data/xsd/Constructivity/Core", ElementName = "Library", IsNullable = true)]
public class UserObject
{
    [XmlArray("Organizations")]
    [XmlArrayItem("OrganizationReference", typeof(Organization))]
    public List<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("a:Libraries")]
    [XmlArrayItem("a:LibraryReference", typeof(Project))]
    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "OrganizationReference", Namespace = "http://www.constructivity.com/api/Data/xsd/Constructivity/Core")]
public class Organization
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.constructivity.com/api/Data/xsd/Constructivity/Access")]
public class Project
{
    [XmlElement("a:Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Add below is the xml string I'm using**`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Library z:Id="i1" xmlns="http://www.constructivity.com/api/Data/xsd/Constructivity/Core" xmlns:a="http://www.constructivity.com/api/Data/xsd/Constructivity/Access" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
  <a:UUID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:UUID>
  <a:Name>admin</a:Name>
  <a:Organizations>
    <a:OrganizationReference>
      <a:Name>buildingSMART</a:Name>
      <a:Access i:nil="true"/>
    </a:OrganizationReference>
    <a:OrganizationReference>
      <a:Name>siemens</a:Name>
      <a:Access i:nil="true"/>
    </a:OrganizationReference>
    <a:OrganizationReference>
      <a:Name>SSMA</a:Name>
      <a:Access i:nil="true"/>
    </a:OrganizationReference>
    <a:OrganizationReference>
      <a:Name>state</a:Name>
      <a:Access i:nil="true"/>
    </a:OrganizationReference>
  </a:Organizations>
  <a:Libraries>
    <a:LibraryReference>
      <a:Name>LignumData_Catalog</a:Name>
      <a:Access i:nil="true"/>
    </a:LibraryReference>
    <a:LibraryReference>
      <a:Name>Constructivity_Core</a:Name>
      <a:Access i:nil="true"/>
    </a:LibraryReference>
    <a:LibraryReference>
      <a:Name>componentassembly_PARTie</a:Name>
      <a:Access i:nil="true"/>
    </a:LibraryReference>
  </a:Libraries>
</Library>
```

**Been stuck on this for too long**

Comment: *Cannot get xml loaded into object* is not a meaningful problem description. What specific problem are you having, and where is your effort to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: I don't know if it's a transcription error, but one of your quotes isn't really a quote: `<a:Access i:nil="true”/>`

Comment: If that's really in the data you're using, that's your problem, because it makes the whole document fail validation

Comment: Yes, its's the data. It's just what the company is sending on their end.

Comment: That puts you in a rough spot, if you don't have any chance of getting a valid document from them you either have to manually process this document, or somehow fix it yourself before you attempt to pass it on to the XML library

Comment: You could bank on the (probably OK) assumption that any time you see `”` it was supposed to be `"`, and just replace them but that's not 100% risk-free

Comment: The data also comes in Json format, I guess I'll work on that, it's probably more reliable anyways. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try code below. I fixed the namespaces. Your xml posted has two errors.  There is an extra double quote and unicode double quote.  I edited the xml in you posting to correct for these issues.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserObject));
            UserObject userObject = (UserObject)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.constructivity.com/api/Data/xsd/Constructivity/Core", ElementName = "Library", IsNullable = true)]
    public class UserObject
    {
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "Organizations", Namespace = "http://www.constructivity.com/api/Data/xsd/Constructivity/Access")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "OrganizationReference", Namespace = "http://www.constructivity.com/api/Data/xsd/Constructivity/Access")]
        public List<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }

        [XmlArray(ElementName = "Libraries", Namespace = "http://www.constructivity.com/api/Data/xsd/Constructivity/Access")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "LibraryReference", Namespace = "http://www.constructivity.com/api/Data/xsd/Constructivity/Access")]
        public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "OrganizationReference")]
    public class Organization
    {
        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Project")]
    public class Project
    {
        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```